# cant cd into existing directory?

Tags: directory, git-bash, cd

[image]

> Im trying to CD into my folder and I keep getting "no such file or directory". I've looked at other solutions on this site and none have worked for me. I've also CD'd into files previously using this exact same format so I'm not getting why it's suddenly not working anymore. Can someone help me out? What am I missing/doing wrong?

Comment: just to make sure it's not a typo... did you mean to leave out a space between cd and the location? `cd /c/Users/...`

Comment: of course it's the most simple solution. *facepalm* thank you, i  managed to completely overlook it